# What is the correct way to instantiate the client object? TypeError: VoximplantApiClient is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, voximplant

What is the correct way to instantiate the client object? it give me this error when i try to
`const client = new VoximplantApiClient(); TypeError: VoximplantApiClient is not a constructor`

Can i get a ES6 imports code example? docs have old require imports
This is how i am importing in my nodejs:
import VoximplantApiClient from '@voximplant/apiclient-nodejs'

docs: https://voximplant.com/docs/references/httpapi/users#adduser

When i do this i`import { VoximplantApiClient } from '@voximplant/apiclient-nodejs';` 
i get

```
import { VoximplantApiClient } from '@voximplant/apiclient-nodejs';
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Named export 'VoximplantApiClient' not found. The requested module '@voximplant/apiclient-nodejs' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

import pkg from '@voximplant/apiclient-nodejs';
const { VoximplantApiClient } = pkg;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is how ES6 modules are emulated in CommonJS.

In order for the node.js modules to work correctly, use the following construction:

```
import VoximplantApiClient from '@voximplant/apiclient-nodejs';
const client = new VoximplantApiClient.default('/path/to/credentials.json');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Nikolas, can you please tell from where i can get the "/path/to/credentials.json" to use the Management API
i can't find any option of my https://manage.voximplant.com/settings/service_accounts

Comment: You need to create service account in Voximplant control panel. Once you do so, you will get the JSON file with service account credentials that you need to pass path to that file instead of '/path/to/credentials.json'